# Prove that if $(a+3)(b-1)=n-3$, where $n\in\mathbb N$ and $a$, $b$ are different factors of $n$, then $3n=q^2$, where $q\in\mathbb N$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$$(a+3)(b-1) = ab - a + 3b - 3 = n-3 \Rightarrow ab - a + 3b = n$$I have no idea how I could use the fact that $a$ and $b$ are different factors of $n$. I'd like to get some help. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this might help : Since $ab-a+3b=n$, it appears that for any $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $3\nmid k$, one has $$k\mid a \Leftrightarrow k\mid b $$

Comment: from $a=ab+3b-n$ you get that $b|a$.

Comment: Could you give me some more help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given condition
$$n = (a+3)(b-1)+3 =ab+3b-a $$
hence $ a=b(a+3)-n$ is a multiple of $b$ and $3b=n-a(b-1)$ is a multiple of $a$. This allows only $a=b$ (which is excluded) or $a=3b$, therefore
$$3n=3(ab+3b-a)=3(3b^2+3b-3b)=(3b)^2.$$
Especially, you *cannot* conclude that $2=3^{2k+1}$ for some $k$: Just note that $n=12$, $b=2$, $a=6$ is an example.